# Avoid reflow of css3 columns after they have been drawn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-columns

I am using css3 columns to display an unordered list in 3 columns. The list items contain lists as well that can be shown or hidden by clicking on the title using jQuery.

The html looks like (with class names to describe the layout and interactions):

```
<ul class="i-display-in-3-columns">
  <li>
    <h3 class="slide-toggle-sibling-list-on-click">column title 1</h3>
    <ul class="i-am-initially-hidden">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="slide-toggle-sibling-list-on-click">column title 2.</h3>
    <p>This can be very long with perhaps an additional paragraph as well.</p>
    <ul class="i-am-initially-hidden">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  /* some more items */
</ul>
```

This works, but every time a sub-list is opened or closed, the columns get redrawn.

I would like to freeze the columns after they have initially been drawn to avoid this reflow so that every item stays in the column it is initially drawn in.

I can of course write a masonry-like solution in javascript to convert my list in 3 lists that are displayed next to each other, but I was hoping that there was an easier solution, preferably in just css or in javascript that keeps my list as a list.

Is that possible or would I just have to rewrite the DOM?

Comment: You could try [`break-before` and `break-after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-before-break-after-break-inside), but [browser support seems to be poor](http://quirksmode.org/css/columns/)

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks, but I don't see how that could stop reflowing of the columns unless I hard-code the column breaks. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was assuming you could hardcode the breaks (I thought you wanted one top-level li per column).

Comment: @bfavaretto No, I will be having 1 to xx top-level `li` elements where each one could have a different height :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve that with CSS columns. There is the option to toggle `visibility` instead of `display` of the child lists, but I'm assuming you don't want that.

Another possible CSS solution is using the flexbox module (and deal with the browser support issues). For example, I believe this might be what you want (working on Chrome 29):

```
.i-display-in-3-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.i-display-in-3-columns>li {
    flex: 1 1 200px; /* 200px is the column width */
}
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j92gB/)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks. I don't see any real difference with floating however - apart from the compatibility :-) - as the titles line up on a horizontal line and animating the inner `li`'s will cause all columns to move down instead of just the one that was clicked in.

Comment: Err, you're right. If the columns didn't have a fixed with, flexbox would be solution, rather than floating; but in this case, floating is enough.